# Initial SessionFactory creation failed in hibernate error

Tags: java, hibernate

firends i m using netbeans ide and its placed hibernate.cfg.xml in default src/java folder
but whenever i run the application its displayed below error :

`Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.HibernateException: /hibernate.cfg.xml not found`

class :

```
public class myutil {
 private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildsf(); 
 public static SessionFactory buildsf() { 
    try {
      // Create the SessionFactory from standard (hibernate.cfg.xml)
      return new Configuration().configure("config/hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
    } catch (Throwable ex) { // Log the exception.
      System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
      throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use :

```
 SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration()
        .configure("config/hibernate.cfg.xml") // give path to hibernate.cfg.xml (recommended)
        .buildSessionFactory();

        return sessionFactory;
```

Check [here](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-load-hibernate-cfg-xml-from-different-directory/) usage. Or directly keep `hibernate.cfg.xml` directly under `src`(not recommended).

Comment: config directory do i need to creat?

Comment: Well it is good keep separate package/dir for configuration. You can give your path there too.

Comment: brother i created a folder config in my application i m using glassfish server still the same error is comming

Comment: public class myutil {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildsf();

    public static SessionFactory buildsf() {
        try {
            // Create the SessionFactory from standard (hibernate.cfg.xml) 
            return new Configuration().configure("config/hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Log the exception. 
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

Comment: i created the config directory inside src folder i m using netbeans ide glassfish server brother